# Pontriagin reflexivity of the character group

Tags: banach-spaces, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, pontrjagin-duality

For an Abelian topological group $G$ by $G^{\wedge}$ we denote the *Pontryagin dual* of $G$, i.e. the group of continuous homomorphisms $G\to\mathbb T:=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|=1\}$. The group $G^{\wedge}$ is endowed with the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets of $G$. A topological group $G$ is called *Pontryagin reflexive* if the canonical homomorphism $G\to (G^\wedge)^\wedge$ is a topological isomorphism.

> **Problem.** Let $G$ be a metrizable Abelian topological group. Is the Pontriagin dual $G^{\wedge}$ of $G$ Pontryagin reflexive?

(This problem was posed 21.09.2017 by Lydia Aussenhofer on [page 71](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=1&page=71) of [Volume 1](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=1) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka)).

Comment: Is it clear that $G^{\wedge}$ is metrizable?

Comment: @YCor, maybe I miss the point of your question, but $\hat G$ doesn't have to be metrisable to ask whether it is reflexive, right?

Comment: @LSpice oh yes you're right, this was irrelevant. Btw I've added the tag Banach space since this is a rich source of non-locally compact abelian groups.

Comment: So, is the point that $G$ need not be locally compact but only metrizable?

Comment: If G is metrizable then $G^\wedge$ is a hemicompact $k$--space. This implies that the canonical mapping $G^\wedge\to G^{\wedge\wedge\wedge}$ is continuous (even an embedding). Only the surjectivity of this mapping is a problem.

Comment: I hope you know that in the case when $G$ is a (metrizable) locally convex space the answer is "yes", see e.g. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1020929201133 or http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2037513

Comment: Why do you call your profile "Lviv Scottish Book" as Lviv is a Ukrainian name for Lwów which was used by the group of Banach. Lwów (or English Lvov) but why Lviv? Looks like an attempt of ukrainisation of the Lwów School of Mathematics.

Comment: @TomekKania ... that guy's profile explains the difference between Lviv and Lwów Scottish Books.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, having read the profile I still think that the Lwów school is described there, especially as the profile picture is the cover of the original one.

Comment: It says the Lviv Scottish Book is a modern-day notebook of problems.  This new notebook was inspired by the Lwów Scottish Book (which ended in 1941).  Indeed, this problem about Pontryagin reflexivity was entered in the Lviv Scottish Book just last week.

Comment: Still something's not right as the book was continued officially in Wrocław (ex-Breslau): http://www.wmi.uni.wroc.pl/pl/New_Scottish_Book

Comment: @TomekKania Dear Tomek Kania, please visit Lviv and you will understand the difference between Lwow and Lviv. By the way Wroclaw continuation of Scottish book is not active for many years and Lviv Scottish Book is our modern Lviv continuation in the same old Scottish Cafe (but also using the power of MathOverFlow). So, what is wrong?

Comment: Taras, I visited the city many times. The mathematical tradition like everything else was discontinued so I find it dodgy that it is claimed otherwise when it comes to the particular case of the Scottish Book.

Comment: In my previous comment I forgot to indicate that $G$ must be complete, I am sorry.

Comment: @TomekKania Tomek, do not be so jealous about Polish history of Lwow. Lviv was (and still is) a multicultural city not just Polish (and you know this very well). I think that it is great that Schottish Cafe was eventually reopened and tourists (including mathematicians) have an opportunity to drink a cofee and discuss mathematics in the same place as Banach and his colleques did 80 years ago. Of course mathematics has changed since those times. Life also has changed. Maybe let us stop this (not entirely mathematical) discussion here. Hope to meet you on some conferences or in Lviv.

Comment: @LvivScottishBook, I am not claiming it is Polish, I simply dislike claimed continuity between the Polish Lwów school (which is continued in Wrocław and elsewhere) and today Lviv, as it is non-existent. I am not alone in this view.

Answer (score 2):

**Not an answer to this problem.**
  For a non-reflexive $G$ see example: Exercise (23.32) in Hewitt & Ross, *Abstract Harmonic Analysis I* (Springer 1963).

Consider a topological vector space $L^p(\mathbb R)$, $0 < p < 1$.
They show that the (separable metrizable) topological group $G = L^p(\mathbb R)$ with operation of addition has no nonzero continuous characters.  So $\widehat{G} = \{0\}$ and $\widehat{\widehat{G}} = \{0\}$, not isomorphic to $G$.

Facts used (Hewitt & Ross include outlines of proofs):

(Day, 1940) this topological vector space has no nonzero continuous linear functionals

(Hewitt & Zuckerman, 1950) every continuous character $\chi$ on $G$ has the form $\chi(x) = \exp(2\pi i f(x))$ for some continuous linear functional $f$.

Comment: This says that this $G$ isn't reflexive, but it doesn't seem to provide an example of a non-reflexive Pontryagin dual. I apologize if I'm missing something...

Comment: You are right.  Not an answer to the original problem.